# Could we consider changing the format of the Edit link?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

Let's say that an unprivileged user tries to edit a post. This edit will require two approvals from privileged users for it to go through. The resulting Edit link (after 1/2 privileged approvals) looks like this:

[image]

(I couldn't find a question that had no approvals on an unprivileged edit)

The first time I saw `edit (1)`, I had no idea what it meant. Can we consider changing the format to:

`edit (0/2)` or `edit (1/2)`, depending on the situation?

I feel that I may not be the only one who was initially confused about the format. `edit (0)` doesn't suggest that two approvals are needed. At least `edit (0/2)` will let prospective privileged users know that further action is necessary before the edit goes through.

Comment: SE sites use tooltips heavily which are generally very clarifying. Did you read the tooltip on this one?

Comment: @Chichiray: I've never noticed that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

The number is the total number of votes, not the number of accept votes. If a post has 1 accept and 1 reject vote, it will say `edit (2)`, which is useful information (it lets people know the suggestion is contested). If the format is going to change it would be nice if the number of rejected votes is still displayed somewhere